# warning '_' is defined but never used @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

I have a function parameter defined as:

`predicate: (x: X) => boolean = (_): boolean => true,`

and *eslint* is still giving me this 'unused' message which seems wonderfully pedantic but still annoying.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I can just remove the '_' and all is good.